# I have started afresh learning Angular JS. Unable to figure out any mistake in the code

Tags: angularjs

```js
// Code goes here

var mainController = function($scope) {
  $scope.message = "Hello Angular";
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainController">
  <h1>{{message}}</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

I am very new to AngularJS. I am unable to figure out the fix to error in the following programme. Following is the link to plnkr.

Comment: There is no link. You should also add the code in code blocks to the questions (the link can also be here but the link is not enough). Also, you should check the developer tools to see what error is coming up in the console.

Comment: you are reading a very old tutorial I guess, switch to something newer.

Comment: This is not a mistake-sniffing service. What is the specific error?  What have you tried to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the very basic angular app you can imagine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainController">
  <h1>{{message}}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the js code:

```
angular.module('app',[])
 .controller('MainController',function($scope) {
  $scope.message = "Hello Angular";
});
```

you can check this plunk
https://plnkr.co/edit/vNjTPZg2kt0xBdb8Xq8Z?p=preview

Comment: I am worried, Couldn't run it in the plunker. https://plnkr.co/edit/NVgDP2KjaZdRDvDgDhUl?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = "Hello Angular";
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainController">
  <h1>{{message}}</h1>
</body>

</html>
```